# How to check quotas for Google Vision API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-vision

I need to check quotas for  Google Vision API programmatically

OR

to set quota limits on API console site directly.

actually I need some way to limit API calls to 1000/month which are free.

Any ideas ?

Comment: When you say "I need to check quotas" .... do you mean determine the current quota limit or determine how much you have used of the quota?

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: Using Stackdriver Metrics, you can define an alert to be fired when usage reaches a value.  The alert can be a service call where you have programatic control.  I am imagining you publishing an app that makes Cloud Vision API calls.  I could imagine you defining a threshold (say 900 calls/month) and when reached, the trigger fires and "disables" your application.  Quota is there to stop "runaway" applications and not to act as a "simple" billing gate.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your project's quotas through the console in two ways:

A) APIs & Services /  All APIs enabled will be shown.

B) IAM & admin / Quotas /  In services filter: Cloud Vision API.

If you want to [edit your quotas](https://cloud.google.com/vision/quotas), you can do it up to their maximum values.

To request an increase above the maximum quota, edit your quota with your requested increase and justification and submit your update.

There isn't yet a way to change / access programmatically the quotas yet. ["Working with Quotas"](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota) has the general information about this,how to manage and monitoring them.